# Axios React Native can not upload photo from image picker

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios

in my app edit Profile page I am having trouble to upload image from image picker to service via API. I pick image without any issues.
Also can sent edit first name last name phone number, but for some reason can not sent image upload

Here is my code:

State:

```
class Profile extends Component {
  state = {
    user: {
      mobile_number: this.props.phoneNumber,
      first_name: this.props.firstName,
      last_name: this.props.lastName,
      image: {
        url: this.props.profileImage
      }
    },
    activity: false,
    editButtonStatus: false,
    photoUploadStatus: false,
    photoUploadUrl: ""
  };
```

Here is my  image picker and i use FormData as well.

```
//Upload image from Liblary
  _pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1
    });

    console.log(result);
    this.setState({ ...this.state, photoUploadStatus: false });
    this.setState({ ...this.state, photoUploadUrl: result.uri });
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append("image", {
      uri: result.uri,
      type: result.type,
      width: result.width,
      height: result.height
    });
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      user: {
        ...this.state.user,
        image: { url: this.state.photoUploadUrl.replace("file://", "") }
      }
    });

    console.log(this.state);
    if (!result.cancelled) {
      //this.setState({ ...this.state, user: { image: { url: result.uri } } });
      this.setState({ ...this.state, photoUploadUrl: result.uri });
    }
  };
```

Here is my Axios request

```
edit = () => {
    console.log(this.state);
    if (this.state.editButtonStatus === false) {
      this.setState({ editButtonStatus: true });
    } else {
      this.setState({ editButtonStatus: false });
      if (this.state.editButtonStatus !== false) {
        this.setState({ activity: true });

        Axios.put(
          EDIT_PROFILE_API,
          { user: this.state.user },
          {
            headers: { appversion: 1.4, apisecret: this.props.api_secret }
          }
        )
          .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            const status = response.status;
            if (status === 200) {
              this.setState({ activity: false });
              console.log(response);
              const userData = response.data;
              this.props.dispatch(loginSuccessful(userData));
              console.log(this.state);
              Alert.alert("Support", "Profile Successfully Updated");
            }
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log({ error });
            this.setState({ activity: false });
            alert(error.response.data.error);
          });
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: are you using the FormData data field your constructing>

Comment: i am using formdata in photo picker function and then i set that formdata in  state, which after i pass as an object in axios along with other states

Comment: hi did u find solution? I am facing same issue in Android only. Everything is fine in iOS

Answer (score 0):

you need to include the content type of the axois request

```
 Axios.put(
          EDIT_PROFILE_API,
          { user: this.state.user },
          {
            headers: { 
               appversion: 1.4, 
               apisecret: this.props.api_secret ,
               'Content-Type: 'multipart/form-data' // add this
} 
          }
        )
```

Comment: this code is passing info to the state    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      user: {
        ...this.state.user,
        image: { url: this.state.photoUploadUrl.replace("file://", "") }
      }
    });

Comment: My server needs to receive my state as raw data. I was triying to use axios to send raw data but it failed.